# Connection pool C3P0 logging

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, connection, c3p0

I have a web application that uses c3p0 as the connection pool. we use hibernate as the orm tool.
Recently, we have been getting connection timeout exceptions. To debug these exception, i enabled the logging fro C3p0 and got some information in logs. Can anybody help me in making complete sense out of it.

```
DEBUG 2012-08-05 14:43:52,590 [com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0] com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GooGooStatementCache: checkinAll(): com.mchange.v2.c3p0.stmt.GlobalMaxOnlyStatementCache stats -- total size: 2; checked out: 0; num connections: 1; num keys: 2
```

from the above, i can observe that the total size of the connection pool is 2. No. of checked out connections are 0. Is this right? And what are num_connections and num keys in the above?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing in the bit of log that you've quoted is a snapshot of the Statement cache, not the Connection pool. There were two cached PreparedStatements, which belonged to a single Connection, at the time that message was logged. Neither of the Statements was checked out/in use.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks steve...I changed the logger in log4j.properties and now have a different set of logs..

Comment: DEBUG 2012-08-05 19:44:02,526 [Timer-2] com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool: trace com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool@5c73f637 [managed: 4, unused: 4, excluded: 0] (e.g. com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewPooledConnection@74904d13)
can you tell me what managed, unused and excluded mean in this log?

Comment: "managed" means the number of Connections in the pool; "unusued" means the number of Connections not currently checked out by clients and so available in the pool; "excluded" means Connections that are checked out, but that experienced some sort of error or fault, such that c3p0 has marked them for disposal rather than reincorporation when the client tries to check them back into the pool.

Answer (score 0):

The exceptions might be due to incorrectly defining the C3P0 settings. Ensure that you link to the right jar file Your application must be linked to "hibernate-c3p0*.jar" and not to "c3p0*.jar". The hibernate.cfg file must have the `hibernate.connection.provider_class` property defined in order for the c3p0 settings to take effect. Below is a sample settings

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.provider_class"> org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider </property>

<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">300</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
```

The log entry specifies that there are 4 connections in the pool and all the 4 connections are available for the application to use. Running a query towards your database to list all the active connections will show the pool connections. For eg in Mysql you could run "`show processlist;`" to see these connections.